# How to connect points in paraview?

Tags: paraview

I have a question. I'm new to Paraview and I'm learning how to use it. I need to make a graph from data that are stored in `.csv` file (2 columns). I have them loaded and converted using `TabletToPoints filter`. I want ask if it's possible to connect these points by point ID so they will create a line (previous point with next point and so on)

I found a solution:

```
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
pdo =  self.GetPolyDataOutput()
numPoints = pdi.GetNumberOfPoints()
pdo.Allocate()
 for i in range(0, numPoints-1):
 points = [i, i+1]
 # VTK_LINE is 3
 pdo.InsertNextCell(3, 2, points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can write a **Programmable Filter** that uses a Python script to create the *vtkPolyData* dataset with the appropriate.

Refer to some of the examples on the ParaView Wiki (http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Quiet late for @NorthySP, I'm afraid, but may be useful for someone who want to build line (`vtkPolyline`) from points in ParaView now:

1. Open data file with points coordinates (txt, csv and other formats ParaView can read and parse).
2. Apply `Programmable Filter` on loaded table.
3. In `Programmable Filter` settings in `Script` field input

```py
# the single input table this filter is applied to
table = inputs[0]

# print table properties and metrics just for sure
print("table: ", table)
print("table.GetNumberOfRows() = ", table.GetNumberOfRows())

num_rows = table.GetNumberOfRows()

# usual vtk workflow: fill vtkPoints first
vtkpoints = vtk.vtkPoints()
for i in range(0, num_rows):
    vtkpoints.InsertPoint(i,
        table.GetValue(i,0).ToFloat(), #x column
        table.GetValue(i,1).ToFloat(), #y column
        table.GetValue(i,2).ToFloat()  #z column
        )
output.SetPoints(vtkpoints)

# allocate vtkCell, representing single line
# if more lines, use output.Allocate(N_OF_LINES, 1) 
output.Allocate(1, 1) 

vtkpolyline = vtk.vtkPolyLine()
vtkpolyline.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(num_rows)
# enumerate points to include in polyline
for i in range(0,num_rows):
    vtkpolyline.GetPointIds().SetId(i, i)
# assign vtkPolyLine graphical object to created vtkCell
output.InsertNextCell(vtkpolyline.GetCellType(),
                      vtkpolyline.GetPointIds())
```

Alternatively you can use `Programmable Source` only instead of `Table`-`Programmable Filter` chain: create `Programmable Source` item, open data file in it's python code, get XYZ from there, and the rest workflow (`vtkPoints` → `vtkPolyline` → `vtkCell`) is just the same as in filter in my example above.

Also my repository with examples of use `Programmable Source` and `Programmable Filter` for lines https://github.com/Ornstein89/paraview_orbit.

[image]