# Overlay a line plot on a 3D volume in Paraview

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, paraview

I want to visualise a line plot (extracted from a plot over line filter along the 'surface' of a model) over the line from which its data was extracted. The Plot Over Line filter allows colouring of the line by a data value, and minor transformations, but I want to set the Z position to a multiplier of the data value.

Here's an image of the basics, which doesn't have Z of the line multiplied by the data value:

[image]

I exported the line plot data, converted the data value (let's call it magnitude) to a pseudo-elevation, and imported the result as an x,y,z points set (where x,y are horizontal coordinates, and z = magnitude expressed as an elevation coordinate).

How do I draw a curve along these points? Without any filters applied, it simply plots as a series of points in space.

Is there another way? I'm sure this is simple, but I'm unable to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified from the question [How to connect points in paraview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438140/how-to-connect-points-in-paraview?rq=1) using the '[Transform the input](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter#Transform_the_input)' example given in the Paraview public Wiki's page on the programmable python filter, and the [vtk docs](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.0/html/a01880.html#a16):

```
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
pdo =  self.GetPolyDataOutput()
numPoints = pdi.GetNumberOfPoints()
pdo.Allocate()
for i in range(0, numPoints-1):
    points = [i, i+1]
    # VTK_LINE is 3
    pdo.InsertNextCell(3, 2, points)
```

Alternatively, here's another script that will do a similar job, modified from a couple of the other examples on the same page as the previous example:

```
# Get a vtk.PolyData object for the input
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
# Get a vtk.PolyData object for the output
pdo = self.GetPolyDataOutput()

numPoints = pdi.GetNumberOfPoints()

# Points for the line:
newPoints = vtk.vtkPoints()
for i in range(0, numPoints):
    # Generate the new points from the input
    coord = pdi.GetPoint(i)
    x, y, z = coord[:3]
    newPoints.InsertPoint(i, x, y, z)

# Add the new points to the PolyData object:
pdo.SetPoints(newPoints)

# Make a line from the new points:
aPolyLine = vtk.vtkPolyLine()

#Indicate the number of points along the line
aPolyLine.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(numPoints)
for i in range(0,numPoints):
   #Add the points to the line. The first value indicates
   #the order of the point on the line. The second value
   #is a reference to a point in a vtkPoints object. Depends
   #on the order that Points were added to vtkPoints object.
   #Note that this will not be associated with actual points
   #until it is added to a vtkPolyData object which holds a
   #vtkPoints object.
   aPolyLine.GetPointIds().SetId(i, i)

#Allocate the number of 'cells' that will be added. We are just
#adding one vtkPolyLine 'cell' to the vtkPolyData object.
pdo.Allocate(1, 1)

#Add the poly line 'cell' to the vtkPolyData object.
pdo.InsertNextCell(aPolyLine.GetCellType(), aPolyLine.GetPointIds())
```

Both solutions result in an image like this (after some fiddling with the Properties panel):

[image: Plot of line data over 3d model]