# Connect points with color from a scalar (Paraview)?

Tags: scalar, paraview, particles

I think my question is quite simple for Programmable filter users with Paraview, but I really have no idea how to do that.

I am trying to visualize the path of one particle with a line colored by a scalar.
(For example, I want to visualize the evolution of the temperature along the path of my particle.)
I have a data file with point coordinates (each line represents its evolution in time) and some scalars (like temperature, diameter) as input.

```
"x", "y", "z", "scalar1", "scalar2"
0, 0, 0, 300, 12.5
0, 12, 7, 302, 35.4
```

After converted that into Table Of Points, I used a Programmable Filter to connect the points (thanks to this subject : [How to connect points in paraview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438140/how-to-connect-points-in-paraview)) :

```
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
pdo =  self.GetPolyDataOutput()
numPoints = pdi.GetNumberOfPoints()
pdo.Allocate()
for i in range(0, numPoints-1):
   points = [i, i+1]
   # VTK_LINE is 3
   pdo.InsertNextCell(3, 2, points)
```

Now, I think I just have to add a command line to specify a color thanks to the scalar associated, but I don't know how to do that. Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Programmable Filter** properties panel, turn on the checkbox for "*Copy Arrays*". That will pass the point data (i.e. the "*scalar1*" and "*scalar2*" fields) to the line output. You can then color the lines by these fields as you would any other field.